# Is heapsort more efficient when used on a minheap or maxheap?

Tags: algorithm, time, heap, time-complexity, heapsort

Just a general question....

Reiterating the title:

Is heapsort more efficient when used on a minheap or maxheap?

NOTE: Using an array-based implementation

Comment: The algorithm is identical. Only the comparisons change.

Comment: That's what my thinking was you're simply changing the comparison from if(x > y) to if(x < y) when it comes to heapifying and percolating.... This is a question on a practice exam so there must be some sort of answer

Comment: Err, that *is* the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is my take on it, and I could be incorrect, but here goes. In theory, they're equally efficient.

Heap Sort works basically by placing all elements into a (min)heap and then, now that they're in heap order, repeatedly removing the minimum element until the heap is empty, giving us the data in increasing order. It's O(nlogn) since we do linear passes through the data, and the heap supports a log n insertion/removal for the work that we do for each element in the data.

If we used a max heap, we'd be repeatedly calling getMax(). This produces a "decreasing order" but you can easily insert these max values from right to left in your final array to get an increasing order.

Comment: I think its the opposite...It actually places them into a max heap. On each iteration the algorithm removes the root and places it at the end of the array and then calls heapify to replace the largest number at the root :P

Comment: Oh. My mistake. Anyways, it still seems like they're interchangeable! In school I was taught that it uses a min heap!

Comment: it doesnt call heapify*** it calls percolate down from n/2 down to index 2. Haha i was just reading about it it says it right here in my book...same thing essentially

Comment: So using your logic I would assume that using a max heap is faster because otherwise it would be calling getMin() or the percolate_down function would need to be changed

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. What is percolate? I've never heard of that in the context of a heap - I was taught that when you remove the root, you swap it with the last element, remove it, and then sink the new root to restore heap order.

Comment: a Percolate_down function would take each sub-heap and make sure that the heap-order property is maintained.  After each root-removal of the heap this function is called on each last non-leaf up to the root to fix any damage done to the heap in the removal of the root for heapsort.  The removal of the root is not done until the root is swapped with the right most leaf

Comment: Ah okay. Basically doing the same thing as what I stated. Honestly, I still think the performance is the same. I'm hesitant to say that max heap is faster.

Comment: Yeah exactly just the opposite. Maybe my prof just put down this question to mess with us lol

Comment: I'm almost 100% sure it's just a basic test to see if you understand how the sort works!